# How to split a zipfile into smaller zipfiles

Tags: archive, zip, split

Is there a way to split a ZIP archive into into smaller zipfiles, where you don't have to make them into one big zipfile to unpack the smaller zipfiles?

For example:
Split 25 GB file into 5 files of 5 GB each --> archive1.zip, ..., archive5.zip. Now I want to extract the data of the archive "archive1.zip" without creating the 25 GB zipfile again.

I know, there is zipsplit, but it only works up to 2 GB and I have files up to 100 GB.

Many thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid there is no way of doing what you want. if you have a huge zip file, you can split it into many smaller files using `split`, but then those files will not be valid `.zip` archives and cannot be decompressed. The format of the compressed archive requires a valid header and when you split the archive, the sub-files you create will not have it.

Think of this like having a very long screwdriver. You can cut this into smaller bits, but only the bit that has the screwdriver's head could still function as a screwdriver. You can't just pick one of the middle pieces and expect it to function as a tiny screwdriver.

I'm afraid you have no choice but to recreate the huge .zip and extract that.

Answer (score 0):

> How to split a zipfile into smaller zipfiles

There is a generic command in Linux actually called [split](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/disco/man1/split.1.html). It supports extensions and a max size and even a max line numbers option:

```
   -a, --suffix-length=N
          generate suffixes of length N (default 2)

   --additional-suffix=SUFFIX
          append an additional SUFFIX to file names

   -b, --bytes=SIZE
          put SIZE bytes per output file

   -C, --line-bytes=SIZE
          put at most SIZE bytes of records per output file

   -d     use numeric suffixes starting at 0, not alphabetic

   -l, --lines=NUMBER
          put NUMBER lines/records per output file
```

And to put them together you can simply `cat` them. 3 examples:

```
cat f1 f2 f3 > original.zip
cat dir/* > original.zip
for file in *; do cat $file >>original.zip; done
```

> Now I want to extract the data of the archive "archive1.zip" without creating the 25 GB zipfile again.

`unzip -l ARCHIVE_NAME` will list the files in a zip. This works on the whole zip to extract 1 file:

```
unzip -j file.zip "dir/in/archive/file.txt"
```

and will restore "dir/in/archive/file.txt" in the current directory. I have not seen proof on this working on a part of the zip file. And then it will be a hit/miss scenario: the file might be partly inside the previous and following part. I doubt it is possible without recreating the file; but that could be done "on the fly".

Comment: I don't think what the OP asks for is possible. They want to be able to extract a single sub-zip file. So first create `huge.zip`, then split to `n1.zip` ... `n100.zip` and then only extract the data in e.g. `5.zip`. This isn't possible since the split files will not be self contained.

Comment: ah I missed that